# Modifying a html element using innerHTML - effect on httprequest

Tags: javascript, html

What is the effect of modifying innerHTML of a div container on http request payload if that div contains form fields?

This is first.html

```
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeDropdown(){
            document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML="";
            var options = "<select name='suffix' id='suffix'></select>";
            document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML=options;         

        }
    </script>
    <br><br>
    <p>testing http header issue</p>
    <a href="javascript:changeDropdown()">Change dropdown</a>
    <form name="test" action="second.html" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name"/>
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="suffix">Suffix</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="divId">
                        <select name="suffix" id="suffix">
                            <option value="Mr" selected=selected>Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs" selected=selected>Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Ms" selected=selected>Ms</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

If I enter a value in two fields, and click submit, this is the value I saw in chrome's request fields. (network->headers)

```
**Request Payload**
      name=Batman&suffix=Mr
```

Now open first.html again. This time click, "change dropdown" link. This will remove all options. Now enter a  name and click submit.

This is the value in Chrome's header

```
 **Request Payload**
      name=Batman
```

the parameter "suffix" disappeared from the http(?) params list. I have clearly added the complete select element back to the form using innerHTML. But it is not being recognized for some reason.

Interestingly enough, if I add a empty option to the select field, it gets picked up.
i.e. change javascript function to

```
 document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML="";
 var options = "<select name='suffix' id='suffix'><option value=''></option></select>";
 document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML=options;
```

If anyone know why this happens and what can I do to rectify this issue without having to add a dummy option as above, please do share. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in the situation where you erase the current content and give it a _blank_ drop down, what should it be posting? Chrome is behaving correctly and as I would expect it to. What you're trying to do is the backwards thing it seems =D

Comment: innerHTML have some problems with form fields. Some browsers (can't remember which, though), wouldn't display any options if a select element was added with innerHTML. JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery, will handle these issues for you. You really should use one.

Comment: @Tejs.. I was expecting that the request object will have param with name "suffix" but value to null. What I was trying to do is.. this page is initially populated with a struts form bean. Lets say suffix=Mr. Now if I click change params and hit submit, what I am expecting is, struts action form will reset suffix to null. But what actually happening is that, action form looks for param named "suffix" in request and it can't find it. so it retains the old value - which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is entirely to do with the fact then when you re-add the `<select>` you add it without any possible options, and hence chrome is ommitting the variable (because it can never be set).

This is confirmed by the fact that your blank `<option>` produces the required result again.